# How to add a UIButton and UITextField to a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a button inside a `ViewController` which should add a `UIView` with `textField` and a `Button` inside it.Now the `UIView` is displaying but, without the `textField` and `Button`.

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonClicked:(id)sender
{

  UIView *searchView;
  if ([self.view viewWithTag:4]) {
    [[self.view viewWithTag:4] removeFromSuperview];
}
  else{
  searchView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 110, 318, 30)];
  searchView.tag =4;
  searchView.alpha = 0.4;
  searchView .backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

 UITextField *searchTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 114, 290, 20)];
 [searchView addSubview:searchTextField];

 UIButton *searchButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(305, 112, 7, 28)];
 [searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(searchMap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 searchButton.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 [searchView addSubview:searchButton];

 [self.view addSubview:searchView];
}

}
```

Comment: your text field y origin is 114 but the search view height is 30 make textfiled and buttons's y origin is 5 or 0 not 114 and 112

Comment: okay :-]....I was adding Y origin relative to whole view...

Comment: Yes instead of taking whole view just take search view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your searchTextField & searchButton frames orgins "y"(114,112),your searchView height only 30,change y position like this

```
UITextField *searchTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 4, 290, 20)];
 [searchView addSubview:searchTextField];

 UIButton *searchButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(305,2, 7, 28)];
 [searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(searchMap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```